# Check and assign to a variable without executing twice ruby

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I want to assign a value from a query mongoid to a variable only if the count is superior to a certain value.

if i do

```
mdl = Mdl.by_params(params) unless Mdl.by_params(params) < limit
```

The query is executed twice, how do i do to check and assign with one query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to retrieve the data from Mongoid to do the comparison.

```
mdl_temp = Mdl.by_params(params)
mdl = mdl_temp unless mdl_temp < limit
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have have a lot of queries like this to do and it's kind of unreadable I thought maybe there was a ruby method to do this directly, or maybe make a method ?

Comment: If you have many queries like this, then separate the logic into standalone method. `mdl = search_by_params(params, limit)`

Comment: Yes that's the method i'm writing, but I want to have results if the most specific queries don't return enough results ^^ maybe I will ask different question, I haven't been enough specific in this one thank you for your time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution depends on what the type of `md1` data is.

Generic solution:

```
((mdl = Mdl.by_params(params)) < limit) && md1 = nil
```

If `md1` is am instance of *mutatable* object, that responds to `replace` (e.g. `Hash`):

```
Mdl.by_params(params).tap do |md| 
  md1.replace(md) unless CONDITION # md[:limit] < limit
end
```